# How to fix my erroneously entered new account name

Tags: discussion

I mistakenly entered my account name as:

**jJames**

Can anyone advise me how to change the account name to:

**james**

... assuming that 'james' is not already taken,

... or to something else?

Perhaps, the easiest solution is to just ask the administrator to delete my account so that I can start again?

Comment: Without mentioning what kind of account the is it is impossible to say.

Comment: Do you mean your Stack Exchange account?

Answer (score 6):

Go to your [Profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/317744/jjames?tab=profile) page, click "Edit Profile & Settings", and change the "Display Name" field. There's no requirement that display names be unique, so you should be able to change it to James or whatever else you like.